# How to push a gateway and route to an OpenVPN client?

Tags: openvpn, ip-routing

I need to setup a OpenVPN network which will probably grow to a serval hundreds of clients in the next few months. Some of the clients are servers and others are devices that need services, hosted on the server(s).

The idea is to use a `10.10.0.0/16` network where all clients are into. The servers shoud have a static VPN IP in the range `10.10.0.1 - 10.10.0.254` and the should have DHCP VPN IP's in the range `10.10.1.1 - 10.10.255.254`. The OpenVPN server (currently 1) has IP `10.10.0.1`

**To distribute the static "server" IP's**, i uncommented `client-config-dir` in the OpenVPN `server.conf` , created a config file for each server in `ccd` with the servers `CN name` as filename and added route `10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0` to `server.conf`. Each client file contains something like this:

```
ifconfig-push 10.10.0.x 10.10.0.1
iroute 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

When i try to ping `10.10.0.1` from one of the servers with an static VPN IP, i the ping is successfull.

**For the DHCP clients** i set some configurations in `server.conf`:

```
dev tun
proto udp
dev tun
mode server
tls-server
ifconfig 10.10.0.1 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool 10.10.1.1 10.10.255.254
route-gateway 10.10.0.1
push "route-gateway 10.10.0.1"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.1"
```

The clients connect correctly and get an IP in the expected range (e.g 10.10.1.61) but when i try to ping to `10.10.0.1`, the ping times out. When i check the gateways with `route -n` i see that the wrong gateway is set:

```
root@somedevice:/home/pi# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.60.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.10.1.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0    <-- should be 10.10.0.1 ?
10.128.60.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

When i add the gateway manually `route add 10.10.0.1 tun0` i'm able to ping the VPN server. I still cannot ping the servers (e.g. 10.10.0.20). When i check `routel`, i notice that the a route to `10.10.0.0/16` is missing.

```
root@somedevice:/home/pi# routel
         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
        default        10.128.60.1    10.128.60.33     dhcp            eth0
      10.10.0.1                                                 link   tun0
      10.10.1.1                          10.10.1.2   kernel     link   tun0
   10.128.60.0/ 24                    10.128.60.33     dhcp     link   eth0
      10.10.1.2              local       10.10.1.2   kernel     host   tun0 local
    10.128.60.0          broadcast    10.128.60.33   kernel     link   eth0 local
   10.128.60.33              local    10.128.60.33   kernel     host   eth0 local
  10.128.60.255          broadcast    10.128.60.33   kernel     link   eth0 local
      127.0.0.0          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
     127.0.0.0/ 8            local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
      127.0.0.1              local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
127.255.255.255          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
            ::1                                      kernel              lo
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            eth0
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            tun0
            ::1              local                   kernel              lo local
fe80::65cf:ce3:fc9f:20fa              local                   kernel            eth0 local
fe80::c648:ccba:8f47:86b7              local                   kernel            tun0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      eth0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      tun0 local
```

When i add this route manually `ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.0.1` i can ping the servers (e.g. 10.10.0.20) :-D

**Questions:**

- How can i push the correct gateway (`10.10.0.1` instead of `10.10.1.1`) to the clients with DHCP addresses?
- How can i push the route `10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.0.1` to the clients with DHCP addresses?

I thought it was done with

```
push "route-gateway 10.10.0.1"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.1"
```

but that doesn't work, what i'm doing wrong?

**----------- UPDATE -----------**

I just noticed that `push "route-gateway 10.10.0.1"` and `push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.1"` pushes the gateway/route to the "static server clients" but not to the clients that receive their VPN IP via DHCP. Why are they not also applied to the DHCP clients?

Answer (score 0):

For my clients (with dhcp ips) working

```
port 53
proto udp
dev tun
tls-server

ca …
cert …
key… 
dh …

cipher …
auth …

local …
server 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.0

max-clients 253
topology subnet
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo no
push "comp-lzo no"
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
username-as-common-name
…
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.1 1"
```

or

```
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 net_gateway 1"
```

to use default client’s gateway.

Comment: `username-as-common-name` and `tls-server` are *absolutely* redundant. The first is useless when you don't use scripts of plugins, and second one is already contained within `server ...`. In the vast majority of cases, you don't need `local ...` too. `port 53` will not work if there is a DNS service on the same machine; I suggest not to invent murtky schemens and use recommended port 1194. Also I'd not specify `auth` and `cipher` for it to be able to negotiate best security parameters. To increase security, `tls-auth` or `tls-crypt` might be added.